# How to take sqlite db from ionic1 and store in external storage

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have created an app using ionic1 and it is live but some serious issues takes place in sqlite that is some datas are not updated in different tables. I would like to know is there any way to take the sqlite db from the app and save it in external storage using ionic1 and angular js. As well as i would like to know is it possible to again push the sqlite.db from external storage to the app and do the normal process.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by taking the database file out and make changes in the database and push the database again to the location

To Take the db from applicationstorage to external storage use this command:

```
function gotoDBBackup () {
  var URI_DB = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'databases/';
  var PARENT_DIR = 'file://mnt/sdcard/';
  var NAME_DB = 'DB.db';
  var NEW_NAME_BACKUP = 'KPbackup.db';
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(URI_DB + NAME_DB, function (fs) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(PARENT_DIR, function (directoryEntry) {
      fs.copyTo(directoryEntry, NEW_NAME_BACKUP, function () {
        $log.log('The database backup was successful.');
        alert('Backup ok');
      });
    });
  });
}
```

To replace db use the command:

```
function replaceDB () {
  /*window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file:///data/data/TestpatchKP/databases/DB.db', function (fs) {
    var parent = 'file://mnt/sdcard/';
    var newName = 'kpupdated.db';
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(parent, function (directoryEntry) {
      fs.copyTo(directoryEntry, newName, function () {
        alert('Backup ok');
      }, failFiles);
    });
  }, failFiles);*/
  var DATABASE_DIR = 'file://mnt/sdcard/';
  var DB_NAME = 'kpupdated.db';
  var NEW_NAME = 'DB.db';
  var URI_DB = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'databases/';

  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(DATABASE_DIR + DB_NAME, function (fs) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(URI_DB, function (directoryEntry) {
      fs.copyTo(directoryEntry, NEW_NAME, function () {
        $log.log('Database has been restored successfully');
        alert('Database restored successfully');
      }, failFiles);
    });
  }, failFiles);
}
```

To remove a db :

```
function removeDB () {
  var NEW_NAME = 'DB.db';
  var URI_DB = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'databases/';
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(URI_DB + NEW_NAME, function (fs) {
    fs.remove(success, fail);
    $log.log('Db removed successfully');
  }, failFiles);
}
```

To view the database use the tool DB for browser. Hope it might help you.